# String behind two variables in directory path laravel 5

Tags: string, file, laravel, variables, path

I want a "/" behind "vandiepen" and "test.txt. Now, Laravel gives an error, because it's not a good path to the file.

**The file "C:\xampp\htdocs\systeembeheer\storage/download/vandiepentest.txt" does not exist**

I tried to put the "/" behind the $folder and the $id variable.

```
$file = storage_path(). "/download/".$folder "/" .$id;
```

When I do that, Laravel gives an error:

**syntax error, unexpected '"/"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you missed `.` (concatenation operator) after `$folder`.

It should be:

```
$file = storage_path() . "/download/" . $folder. "/" . $id;
```

Also you can use **[DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php)**.

```
$file = storage_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "download" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $folder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $id;
```